# My webview load only https but i want http websites. Is that possible?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, webview, uiviewcontroller

My class:

```
import UIKit
import WebKit
import PKHUD

class ViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate, WKUIDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var webView: WKWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        webView.navigationDelegate = self
        webView.load(URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://www.google.com.br")!))
    }

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didStartProvisionalNavigation navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        PKHUD.sharedHUD.contentView = PKHUDProgressView()
        PKHUD.sharedHUD.show()
    }

    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        PKHUD.sharedHUD.contentView = PKHUDProgressView()
        PKHUD.sharedHUD.hide()
    }
}
```

But websites with only 'http' don't works. Is that possible?
Specs:
iOs: 11.4
Swift language
Xcode 9.4.1

Answer (score 3):

> To support also an unsecure connection do this:

1.Open the info.plist file

2.Add the Key called `App Transport Security` Settings as Dictionary (Dictionary should be the default type)

3.Add the Subkey called `Allow Arbitrary Loads` as Boolean (Boolean should be the default type). Set it to YES

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eyEoN.png)

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This is happening because transport security has blocked unsecure HTTP connection. to allow HTTP, open your Info.plist as source code and add the following.

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>yourDomain.com</key> // here put your domain or ip addres
        <dict>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to set **Allow Arbitrary Loads** value to true from plist.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes but for this you need to add in your info.plist

> NSAppTransportSecurity <- Type Dictionary
>
> NSAllowsArbitraryLoads <- Type Boolean Value YES

[Apple Documents](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html)